# window.addEventListener not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a window.addEventListener to trrigger a 'pageShow' event...I added this to suppport IE 8,9,10,11 , firefox and chrome....

The below piece of code works fine for chrome and IE 11 but fails for IE 8...

Please provide some suggestion how to handle this?

```
 if (!window.addEventListener){
        alert('Not Window')
        window.attachEvent('onpageShow',checksession,false);
    }
    else{
        alert('Window')
    window.addEventListener('pageshow',checksession,false);
    }
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: I honestly don't know what the `pageshow` event is, but you've capitalized `S` in `"onpageShow"` in the `attachEvent` version, and you're passing an unnecessary `false` argument to `attachEvent`. Try fixing those.

Comment: ...from [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it appears as though `pageshow` is supported starting in IE11.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I changed it but I dont see the checksession being called..

Comment: @lightswitch05: It does not get called for IE8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749990/window-addeventlistener-not-working-on-ie8?noredirect=1#comment36514027_23749990